# Magento record count memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted error

Tags: magento-1.9, query, memory

I having a custom table with 5lakhs records, i am writing query and get count of row using `$collection->getCount()` method, but it throw an error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted.

```
Table (id,firstname,lastname,address)
```

this table having 5lakhs records

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
            echo $collection->getCount(); exit;
            if($collection->getCount()) {
                foreach($collection as $_collection) {
                    $this->email[$_collection->getEmail()] = $_collection->getId();
                    $this->f_name[$_collection->getFirstname()] = $_collection->getId();
                    $this->l_name[$_collection->getLastname()] = $_collection->getId();
                }
            }
```

Here i wrote this query in that corresponding table model file,that why use the $this object.

i also increase my `max_memory` limit to `1024M` in my php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a common issue in dealing with large catalogs.
The method you are using `->getCount()` will eventually lead to:

```
public function count()
{
   $this->load();
   return count($this->_items);
}
```

And here you can see the issue: you are essentially trying to load 500 000 records. (I had to google what a lakh measurement was, something newly learnt)

Instead of using count, use `->getSize()`

`$collection->getSize();`

Comment: Hmm its working,but when i print the $_collection->getFirstname(), the same issue is again repeating.may i know what is the problem behind in that.

Comment: I gather that you are doing this inside the `foreach($collection as $_collection) { ....  }` ? The same issue, the foreach will load the entire collection into an array.  you need to work with your collection in pages. There are a few ways to solve this. simply google 'working with large collections in magento'

Comment: @ProxiBlue foreach will load the collection ? will you please explain it more? or you have any link that clearly shows the "loading" effect of foreach ?

Comment: foreach will iterate an array ... a collection is really just an array of objects. In order for the foreach language construct to work, it needs to load the collection, so it can become an array (of objects) to iterate over. Read this for a more detailed explanation: http://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/

Comment: thanks for your answer, i study how to handle the large-collection in magento. and implemented. now its working without any issue